# Is the Promise constructor synchronous?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Say the code in a Promise constructor contains synchronous assignments. I have something like this:

```
function x() {
    let rejector = null;
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rejector = reject;
        // async code follows - setTimeout, network requests, etc.
    });
    return rejector;
}
```

Is the synchronous code in the Promise constructor guarunteed to execute, in this example, before the return statement of its containing function?

For me thus far it works *every* time — `typeof x() == 'function'` is always `true`; but I feel like I just happen to be winning a race. I ran it through a loop, 10^8 times, checking to see if I'd ever 'lose the race', but no, it was always successful. Does this always hold?

Comment: `rejector` is guaranteed to be set to `reject`.

Comment: As a note, what you are doing there (passing the `reject` out of the scope of the Promise callback) is considered as an anti-pattern.