# microtask vs synchronous code execution order

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, event-loop

I'm trying to understand the order of execution of javascript asynchronous code in the event loop.

Here's my very short code snippet.

How can we explain the actual order of execution: `in promise` -> `end` -> `in then`? Why does the promise constructor run before the `console.log('end')`?

```js
const p = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  console.log('in promise')
  res()
})

p.then(() => console.log('in then'))

console.log('end')
```

Comment: We can explain it by saying that `then` callbacks are asynchronous, which you presumably already know if you have heard the terms "microtask" and "event loop". What more information are you looking for?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry for a clumsy question. What I cannot understand is why the promise (which is asynchronous) is executed before the final `console.log`, while the `then`-block is executed after it.

Comment: No. [The `new Promise` constructor is not asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59415313/1048572). Only `then` callbacks are asynchronously executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that runs in the promise constructor, logging out "in promise"

The second thing that runs is `p.then`, setting up some code to run at a future time.

The thing thing to run is console.log('end');

Your code is now done running, so execution returns to the event loop. A promise is in the resolved state, so microtasks run and the `.then` callback logs out 'in then'.

Comment: why does the promise constructor run before `console.log`?

Comment: Because it's on an earlier line. Promise constructors are synchronous (as are all constructors). The code starting with `(res, rej)` runs immediately, during the construction of the promise.

Comment: @Nickolas Tower Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I didn't understand.